# how to paginate a query() cakephp ?

Tags: cakephp

```
    $v = array(1,11.38,15.8);
    $sortByPrice = $this->Product->query
    (
    "SELECT *,
    CASE `Product`.`currency` 
        WHEN '1' THEN $v[0]
        WHEN '2' THEN $v[1]
        WHEN '3' THEN $v[2]
    END AS 'ratio'          
    FROM `products` AS `Product` 
        LEFT JOIN `marks` AS `Mark` ON (`mark_id` = `Mark`.`id`)
        LEFT JOIN `categories` AS `Category` ON (`category_id` = `Category`.`id`)
        RIGHT JOIN `photos` AS `Photo` ON (`Photo`.`product_id` = `Product`.`id`)
    ORDER BY price*ratio DESC"
    );
```

How to paginate this query ? I read on book.cake but it doesnt explain very well

Comment: is there a reason NOT to use the wrapper methods (find and paginate) from the DBO datasource? also you didnt mention your cake version. in 1.3 and 2.x virtual fields are the way to go here.

Comment: i tried to use find, but i could not insert CASE in a find...i use 2.x version of the cakephp

Comment: Use `find()` with a [virtual field](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html).

Answer (score 0):

In that case if your current page is corresponds to Product
than it is simply in cakephp 3 look like this:

```
$this->paginate($sortByPrice);
$this->set(compact('$sortByPrice'));
```

And as the previous comments says its better to use in-built query function of  cakephp